# Opening another form with a method/function that is on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

is it possible to open my second form, when the method/or function opening the 2nd form
is on another thread?

i have read other threads related to this..
but it seems i cant figure out how to use the **invoke**

here's how i open the 2nd form
when im calling this.. nothing just happens..(because its on the 2nd thread)

```
TimerMode f2 = new TimerMode();
f2.ShowDialog();
```

please help me. i newbie to multi -threading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be doing something. That is because `ShowDialog` will run its own message loop. The `TimerMode` form should at least be visible and functioning. But, you are right, this really is not the best practice especially if this form will be interacting with the other forms which are already running on the main UI thread.

Here is how you might do it.

```
anotherForm.Invoke(
  (MethodInvoker)(() =>
  {
    new TimerMode().ShowDialog();
  }));
```

Note that `anotherForm` is a reference to one of your other forms which is already hosted on the main UI thread.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the sample code you have given. it works like a charm, but i still got a problem, i think this is still related to this threading.. if i use the .ShowDialog() it somehow stay's there.. the following codes is not executed.. if i use the .Show() it now reads the following set of codes.. but the TimerMode For looks like its on a Not-Responding state(like in windows xp when a application is hanging). this is what i found out. thank you again for the time answering.

Comment: also just to add, if TimerMode is now show.. i cant visible = false the first form. its like nothing happens. =(

Comment: You are going to have to post more of your code. Without seeing the bigger picture I can only speculate.

Comment: Hi , i figure out one of my methods is causing the hanging problem. thanks Brian . your invoking tip help me alot =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute on the main window thread
Try the following:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
    TimerMode f2 = new TimerMode();
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

This will create it on the right thread.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.. ill try you tips and give you a feedback. thanks

Comment: hi again. i tried to use the sample code you gave me. but no luck, (Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer (CS0026)) is being highlighted as the error.. also will this help me on how to do like on vb6( form2.show? ) thanks again